# Need help for onBlur event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page contained multiple input (creating from code behind) in which two of them need to check whether or not is empty.

So I simply create 2 input as below

```
<input id='input_1' title='first_input' tabindex='1' onBlur='check_empty(document.form1.input_1);'></input>
<input id='input_2' title='second_input' tabindex='2' onBlur='check_empty(document.form1.input_2);'></input>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
function check_empty(field){
    if(field.value === ""){ 
       alert('Please enter' + field.title); 
       field.focus();
    }
};
```

The problem I've been facing is whenever I leave input1 empty and press TAB , the focus is now on input2 and from the JavaScript it change the focus from input2 to it and then since the input2 lost focus the JavaScript change the focus from input1 to it too! and so on.

What should I do?

Comment: the onBlue events are supposed to call the `check_empty` function, but where is it declared because I am seeing the `myFnc` instead ???

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @marvinIsSacul Sorry about that , I've change it now

Answer (score 0):

1- Your `onblur` is pointing to a non-existing function `check_empty()`.

2- You need to invoke the function with proper parameters so that it can check the field. There is no need to pass ids to the function. You can just pass `this` and it will point to the element that invoked the function.

3- Having the `alert()` pop up will cause the focus automatically be removed from the text-box whenever you click the OK button to dismiss the alert, causing the `onblur` function to get triggered infinity. A better solution is to post the message on the page in a way to inform the user without disrupting his/her experience.

```js
function check_empty(field){
   var msg = document.getElementById('message');
   msg.innerHTML = '';
    
    if(field.value === ""){ 
       field.focus();
       msg.innerHTML = '<br>Please enter ' + field.title; 
       
    }
};
```

```html
Click inside a field, then try to leave it empty. <br>
<input id='input_1' title='first_input' tabindex='1' onBlur="check_empty(this);">
<input id='input_2' title='second_input' tabindex='2' onBlur="check_empty(this);">
<div id='message'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not working. I also run your code snippet and it's not working either.

Comment: On your code snippet , I clicked the first box then press TAB it shows up the same problem.

Comment: @Izle that is because of Stackoverflow snippet design. If you test this code in your website, it will work. Try adding more text boxes with same onblur event. Only last textbox will not trigger it if you press tab. But if you try to focus on other textboxes it will be triggered even for the last field

Comment: I've tried that and still face the same problem.
May be need to change the way of input validation.